# Add icon to menu item from java code (android 2.3)

Tags: java, android, menu, icons

Is there a possibility, to add an image to menu item, from java code (not from xml file)?

For example (in XML):

```
item android:id="@+id/help" 
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
     android:title="@string/help"
```

Second line adds a picture (icon) to an item, but this is XML file.

In code, when I'm making a menu there is only few constructor to add an item
For example:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

```
    menu.add(0,0,0,"Czerwony");
```

But anyone with image (only title text/string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu.add((0,0,0,"Czerwony").setIcon(R.drawable.edit_icon);
```

Please Also see this article: [How to create Menus in Android in Java Code](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/28673.aspx)

Comment: mhm.. indeed ; ) I had read this blog, but then i was working with developer.android.com :P Thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Czerwony").setIcon(int iconRes);`

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon%28int%29)